# Is there a security downside to having iptables ignore the loopback interface?

Tags: iptables, loopback

I have the following rules in my iptables (I cut out the rules that aren't relevant to this question):

```
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT
:OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING -i lo -j NOTRACK 
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j NOTRACK 
COMMIT

*filter
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 ! -i lo -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
```

I've put this into place because I had overflows on ip_conntrack due to interacting with a server locally over the loopback.  Is there any security issues I'm missing here?

Comment: should I also add <code>-A OUTPUT -i lo -j NOTRACK</code>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say no. `lo` is not accessible from outside, so if an attacker has gotten to a point where he could attack that interface, you already have bigger problems to worry about.